# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. on mac m1

Tags: android, macos, flutter, gradle, apple-m1

I've cloned repo of existing project on github. After launching I got next log:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for arm64 in debug mode...
[flutter_background_geolocation] Purging debug resources in release build
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     /Users/arthur/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/5df5e982d3c927d859e132fe495f1ced/appauth-0.10.0/AndroidManifest.xml:24:5-32:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I've reinstall android studio, upgraded gradle (through homebrew) and flutter clean but problem still exist. Working on Macbook Air M1.

Answer (score 1):

1. Upgrade your Gradle via Android Studio
2. Check your project sdk

worked for me

Comment: update kotlin version

Comment: what version of gradle should I install? I currently have 7.4.2